# How to linkify internal text document cross-references?

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing

I'm making a web version of a collection of docs with plaintext like this:

> ...as found in article 6, depending on...

I'm writing code to add relative URL anchors (linkify):

```markdown
...as found in <a href="article_6">article 6</a>, depending on...
```

I'm open to any programming language, and currently have Ruby + regex code that handles this simple case:

```rb
    with_single_article_links = html.gsub(/(article \d+)/i) do
      last_match = Regexp.last_match
      "<a href=\"last_match.gsub(' ', '_')\">#{last_match}</a>"
    end
```

But I'm looking for ideas on handling more complex cases like these, with multiple citations:

- ...as found in **article 6 or 7**, depending on...
- ...as found in **article 6, 7 or 8**, depending on...
- ...as found in **article 6, 7 or 8 bis**, depending on...

If I keep going with my current code, I'd probably have two levels of regexes: a first match for `article \d+`, and then a second check for one of these complex cases.

But is there some other approach I could take? I'm open to any programming language and technique. This is basically a reality check for me that I'm using a decent method.

**Update:** Expanding the regex, this is working so far:

```
article (\d+)((, \d+)* or (\d+))?
```

Live view: https://regex101.com/r/WHtM5C/1

The second group will just need some simple parsing of the comma-separated list.

Comment: If there is a citation `as found in article 6, 7 or 8`, then you want to convert it to `as found in [6][7][8]`. Did I understand it correctly? [6][7][8] is just an example. I just gave an example of citations linked to those references (similar to Wikipedia)

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Yes, pretty much exactly like that. I got that kind of output with the state machine / builder approach by nPn: https://replit.com/@dogweather/TurquoiseAwareCryptos#main.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a second answer because I did not want to make any major changes after the first answer had been up voted.

As you noticed,  this is sort of a state machine so you can start "building" a number when you first see the digits and then complete the number when you reach a token that indicates you have reached the end of the number definition.  If the number building gets complicated you can even start a nested builder, ie a NumberBuilder and send tokens to that until you reach the end of the number definition and then ask the builder for the number.

```
input = "as found in article 6 or 7, depending on\nas found in article 6, 7 bis or 8, depending on\nas found in article 6, 7 or 8 bis, depending on"

class TextReader
  attr_reader :builder, :text

  def initialize(text, builder)
    @text = text
    @builder = builder
  end

  def parse()
    stream = text.split(/(?=\s|,)/)
    stream.each do |token|
      case token
      when /^\s+$/
        builder.convert_space(token)
      when /^\s*,$/, /^\s+or$/
        builder.convert_joiner(token)
      when /^\s*\d+$/
        builder.convert_digits(token)
      when /^\s*as$/
        builder.convert_as(token)
      when /^\s*found$/
        builder.convert_found(token)
      when /^\s*in$/
        builder.convert_in(token)
      when /^\s*article$/
        builder.convert_article(token)
      when /^\s*bis$/
        builder.convert_bis(token)
      else
        builder.convert_other(token)
      end
    end
  end
end

class HTMLBuilder
  attr_reader :html

  def initialize()
    @html = ""
  end

  def convert_space(token)
    html << token
  end

  def convert_joiner(token)
    @joiner = true
    process_number if @number
    html << token
  end

  def convert_other(token)
    process_number if @number
    @as = @found = @in = @article = @joiner = @number = false
    html << token
  end

  def convert_digits(token)
    @number = token   
  end

  def convert_bis(token)
    if @number 
        @number << token
        process_number
    else
        html << token
    end
  end

  def process_number()
    token = @number
    @number = false
    token =~ /^\s*(\d+)(.+)*/
    if @article
      if @joiner
        html << " <a href=\"article_#{$1}#{$2}\" #{$1}#{$2}>"
      else
        html << " <a href=\"article_#{$1}#{$2}\" article #{$1}#{$2}>"
      end
    else
      html << token
    end
  end

  def convert_as(token)
    @as = true
    html << token
  end

  def convert_found(token)
    @found = true if @as
    html << token
  end

  def convert_in(token)
    @in = true if @found
    html << token
  end

  def convert_article(token)
    @article = true if @in
  end
end

builder = HTMLBuilder.new
reader = TextReader.new(input, builder)
reader.parse
puts "output:"
puts builder.html

=>
output:
as found in <a href="article_6" 6> or <a href="article_7" 7>, depending on
as found in <a href="article_6" 6>, <a href="article_7 bis" 7 bis> or <a href="article_8" 8>, depending on
as found in <a href="article_6" 6>, <a href="article_7" 7> or <a href="article_8 bis" 8 bis>, depending on
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is going to seem like total overkill and really verbose,  but the first thing that comes to mind to use a builder pattern by splitting your input into tokens and then converting each token based on where you are in the stream.

```
input = "as found in article 6 or 7, depending on\nas found in article 6, 7 or 8, depending on\nas found in article 6, 7 or 8 bis, depending on"

class TextReader
  attr_reader :builder, :text

  def initialize(text, builder)
    @text = text
    @builder = builder
  end

  def parse()
    stream = text.split(/(?=\s|,)/)
    stream.each do |token|
      case token
      when /^\s+$/
        builder.convert_space(token)
      when /^\s*,$/, /^\s+or$/
        builder.convert_joiner(token)
      when /^\s*\d+$/
        builder.convert_number(token)
      when /^\s*as$/
        builder.convert_as(token)
      when /^\s*found$/
        builder.convert_found(token)
      when /^\s*in$/
        builder.convert_in(token)
      when /^\s*article$/
        builder.convert_article(token)
      else
        builder.convert_other(token)
      end
    end
  end
end

class HTMLBuilder
  attr_reader :html

  def initialize()
    @html = ""
  end

  def convert_space(token)
    html << token
  end

  def convert_joiner(token)
    @joiner = true
    html << token
  end

  def convert_other(token)
    @as = @found = @in = @article = @joiner = false
    html << token
  end

  def convert_number(token)
    token =~ /^\s*(\d+)/
    if @article
      if @joiner
        html << " <a href=\"article_#{$1}\" #{$1}>"
      else
        html << " <a href=\"article_#{$1}\" article #{$1}>"
      end
    else
      html << token
    end
  end

  def convert_as(token)
    @as = true
    html << token
  end

  def convert_found(token)
    @found = true if @as
    html << token
  end

  def convert_in(token)
    @in = true if @found
    html << token
  end

  def convert_article(token)
    @article = true if @in
  end
end

builder = HTMLBuilder.new
reader = TextReader.new(input, builder)
reader.parse
puts "output:"
puts builder.html


=>
output:
as found in <a href="article_6" article 6> or <a href="article_7" 7>, depending on
as found in <a href="article_6" article 6>, <a href="article_7" 7> or <a href="article_8" 8>, depending on
as found in <a href="article_6" article 6>, <a href="article_7" 7> or <a href="article_8" 8> bis, depending on
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of alternative approach I was wondering about. And this solves a further issue issue I hadn't mentioned: The ability to do both "article ... or" as well as "articles ... and". And then Parts as well as Articles. I guess I'd call your solution "a state machine implemented with the Builder pattern". Is that a good description?  I took your code and worked it further: https://replit.com/@dogweather/TurquoiseAwareCryptos#main.rb

Comment: BTW, do you have an idea how you'd extend your code to handle numbers with an internal space? E.g., "8 bis" and "8 ter" are both "numbers" in legal numbering? Maybe pre-process the "stream", joining together tokens such as "8" and "bis"?

Comment: @Dogweather I added a second answer to show how you could handle the more complicated numbers such as "8 bis"  (I have know idea what that means :) )